# Nativescript: http requests under proxy inside an app on linux

Tags: android, proxy, nativescript, android-virtual-device

I have a `Nativescript` app that needs to do some http calls. A proxy config is set on my local machine. I want to make Nativescript start the emulator with the proxy conf like `emulator -avd <NAME> -http-proxy host:port` but I didn't found a solution to perform that.

I also tried to use `proxy-lib` nativescript plugin but in vain.

How can I do that ?

Thx.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No I didn't. I tried to set JAVA_OPTS but in vain